# getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in android

Tags: android, listview

I am using pinned-section-listview from [here](https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview) and getting following error after scrolling,

```
07-31 17:52:46.640: E/InputEventReceiver(25288): Exception dispatching input event.
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:6916)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5442)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3310)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3654)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7143)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2238)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1935)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1938)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1392)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2408)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1886)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7323)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3560)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3490)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4637)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4597)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4749)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:163)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4717)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4771)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:747)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:567)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:534)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:733)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
07-31 17:52:46.657: E/AndroidRuntime(25288):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


package com.benego.Fragment;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.text.AndroidCharacter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.benego.AppCache;
import com.benego.MainActivity;
import com.benego.PinnedSectionListView.PinnedSectionListAdapter;
import com.benego.R;
import com.benego.Entity.LocalPhraseInfo;
import com.benego.Model.LocalPhraseModel;

public class PhraseResultFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private String CategoryID = null;
    //private String CategoryName = null;

    public final String SOURCE_HOME = "home";
    public final String SOURCE_NEARBY_VENUE = "nbv";
    public final String SOURCE_NEARBY_SUB_CATEGORY = "nbsc";

    private LocalPhraseResultAdapter adapter = null;
    private List<LocalPhraseInfo> phrases = null;

    public String getBundleString(String key, String defaultValue) {
        if (getArguments().containsKey(key))
            return getArguments().getString(key);
        else
            return defaultValue;
    }

    /**
     * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phraseresult_fragment, container,
                false);

        //View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        SearchFragment search_fragment = (SearchFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.phraseresultsearchfragment);
        search_fragment.resultFragmemt = this;

        LocalPhraseModel model = new LocalPhraseModel();
        phrases = null;

        String fromPage = getBundleString("from", SOURCE_HOME);

        if (fromPage == SOURCE_HOME)
        {
            CategoryID = getBundleString("CategoryID", "all");
            //CategoryName = getArguments().getString("CategoryName", "All");
            search_fragment.categoryId = CategoryID;
            phrases = model.GetPhrases(CategoryID, null);
        }
        else if (fromPage == SOURCE_NEARBY_SUB_CATEGORY)
        {
            String fsSubCategoryID = getBundleString("SubCategoryID", "all");
            search_fragment.subCategoryId = fsSubCategoryID;
            phrases = model.GetPhrasesBySubCategoryID(fsSubCategoryID, null);
        }
        else if (fromPage == SOURCE_NEARBY_VENUE)
        {
            String[] subCategoryIds = getArguments().getStringArray("SubCategoryIDs");
            search_fragment.subCategoryIds = subCategoryIds;
            phrases = model.GetPhrasesBySubCategoryIDs(subCategoryIds, null);
        }

        ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        adapter = new LocalPhraseResultAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), phrases);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }   

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView(); 

        try {
            Fragment fragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.phraseresultsearchfragment);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }   


    public void PlayAudio(int phraseID){
        //set up MediaPlayer    
        try {
            LocalPhraseModel model = new LocalPhraseModel(); 
            byte[] audio = model.GetAudio(phraseID);
            if (audio != null)
            {
                File tempMp3 = File.createTempFile(String.valueOf(phraseID), ".mp3", getActivity().getCacheDir());
                tempMp3.deleteOnExit();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempMp3);
                fos.write(audio);
                fos.close();

                final FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(tempMp3);
                FileDescriptor fd = fs.getFD();

                MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
                mp.setDataSource(fd);
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        try {
                            fs.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void RefreshView(List<LocalPhraseInfo> results)
    {
        this.adapter.setListData(results);
    }

    public class LocalPhraseResultAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements PinnedSectionListAdapter {
        private Context mContext;
        private List<LocalPhraseInfo> _results = null;

        public LocalPhraseResultAdapter(Context c, List<LocalPhraseInfo> phrases) {
            mContext = c;
            this.setResults(phrases);       
        }

        public int getCount() {
            int size = this._results.size();
            return size;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return _results.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        private void setListData( List<LocalPhraseInfo> newListData ) {
            this.setResults(newListData);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }//met

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View cView;
            if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                        // attributes
                cView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                        R.layout.phraseresult_item, null);
            } else {
                cView = convertView;
            }

            LocalPhraseInfo pInfo = _results.get(position);
            cView.setTag(pInfo);

            if (pInfo.getPhraseID() > 0)
            {
                cView.findViewById(R.id.phraseresult_row).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                cView.findViewById(R.id.phraseresult_section).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                cView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        LocalPhraseInfo pInfo = (LocalPhraseInfo)v.getTag();
                        PlayAudio(pInfo.getPhraseID());
                    }
                });

                TextView txtNativeView = (TextView) cView.findViewById(R.id.nativePhraseView);
                TextView txtTranslationView = (TextView) cView.findViewById(R.id.translationPhraseView);

                txtNativeView.setText(pInfo.getNativePhrase());
                txtTranslationView.setText(pInfo.getTranslationPhrase());

                ImageView sv = (ImageView)cView.findViewById(R.id.phraseSoundIcon);
                if (pInfo.getIsSoundClipExists())
                    sv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                ImageButton detailBtn = (ImageButton)cView.findViewById(R.id.btnphraseDetail);
                if (pInfo.getHasRelatedPhrases() || pInfo.getIsRootPhrase())
                {
                    detailBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    detailBtn.setTag(pInfo);

                    detailBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            LocalPhraseInfo pInfo = (LocalPhraseInfo)v.getTag();

                            Bundle args = new Bundle();
                            args.putString("from", "home");
                            args.putSerializable("Phrase", pInfo);

                            MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
                            mainActivity.addFragment(mainActivity.LOCAL_TAB, PhraseDetailFragment.class, args);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cView.findViewById(R.id.phraseresult_row).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                cView.findViewById(R.id.phraseresult_section).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                TextView txtSectionView = (TextView)cView.findViewById(R.id.phraseresult_section_text);
                txtSectionView.setText(pInfo.getSubCategoryName());
            }

            return cView;
        }

        @Override public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            LocalPhraseInfo info = (LocalPhraseInfo)getItem(position);
            if (info.getPhraseID() > 0)
                return 2;
            else
                return 1;
        }

        @Override public boolean isItemViewTypePinned(int viewType) {
            return viewType == 1;
        }

        private void setResults(List<LocalPhraseInfo> results)
        {
            List<LocalPhraseInfo> sectioned = new ArrayList<LocalPhraseInfo>();

            String key = null; 
            Iterator<LocalPhraseInfo> localIterator = results.iterator();
            while (localIterator.hasNext()) {
                LocalPhraseInfo info = localIterator.next();
                if (key == null || !key.endsWith(info.getSubCategoryName()))
                {
                    key = info.getSubCategoryName();
                    sectioned.add(this.getSectionPhraseInfo(info));
                }

                sectioned.add(info);
            }

            this._results = sectioned;
        }

        private LocalPhraseInfo getSectionPhraseInfo(LocalPhraseInfo phrase)
        {
            LocalPhraseInfo info = new LocalPhraseInfo();
            info.setSubCategoryID(phrase.getSubCategoryID());
            info.setSubCategoryName(phrase.getSubCategoryName());
            return info;
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me. I am struggling from last two days.

Comment: see the line where u r getting this error and put the code here

Comment: Access the first array element with 0, the second with 1, and so on.

Comment: Try replacing `LocalPhraseInfo info = (LocalPhraseInfo)getItem(position);` with `LocalPhraseInfo info = (LocalPhraseInfo)getItem(position-1);`. Can't guarantee that it works, but give it a shot.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you read closely the `getItemViewType` method documentation, it says :

> Integers must be in the range 0 to getViewTypeCount() - 1

In your case, in the range [0, 1]

Comment: This is unbelievable, but so true and an hour-saver :)

Comment: superb, the main point is we need to start ViewType from 0. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have-

```
if (info.getPhraseID() > 0)
  return 2;
else
  return 1;
```

Shouldn't it be-

```
if (info.getPhraseID() > 0)
  return 1;
else
  return 0;
```